# Convert a binary number to Base 64

Tags: php, base64

I know this is a pretty silly question, but I don't know what to do.

I have an arbitrary binary number, say,

```
1001000000110010000000100100000010000011000000010001000001011000110000110000011100011100000011000000010010011000100000000000000100100000010110001100001000000111
```

I want to convert it to Base 64 using PHP - and every way I try gives me a different result. Even different online converters convert it differently:

http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/
http://convertxy.com/index.php/numberbases/

PHP's base_convert only works up to base36, and base64_encode expects a string.

What do I do?

**UPDATE**: I implemented the solution functions suggested by **@binaryLV**, and it did work well.

However, I compared the results to PHP's built-in **base_convert**. It turned out that base_convert to base36 returns shorter values that the custom base64 function! (And yes, I did prepend a '1' to all the binary numbers to ensure leading zeros aren't lost).

I have noticed, too, that **base_convert** is quite innacurate with large numbers. So I need is a function which works like base_convert, but accurately and, preferably, up to base 64.

Comment: 1) Want the number to be converted to base 64 directly? - 2) want the binary number be converted to ASCII first then base 64? 3) or what?

Comment: @Mido - I don't really see any difference between (1) and (2) - what matters to me is the outcome. I want to be able to convert the binary number (not the string of '0's and '1') to base 64 in a consistent manner, and then to be able to convert it back to binary.

Answer (score 5):

Length of a string in example is 160. It makes me think that it holds info about 160/8 characters. So,

1. split string into parts, each part holds 8 binary digits and describes single character
2. convert each part into a decimal integer
3. build a string from characters, that are made from ASCII codes from 2nd step

This will work with strings with size `n*8`. For other strings (e.g., 12 binary digits) it will give unexpected results.

Code:

```
function bin2base64($bin) {
    $arr = str_split($bin, 8);
    $str = '';
    foreach ( $arr as $binNumber ) {
        $str .= chr(bindec($binNumber));
    }
    return base64_encode($str);
}

$bin = '1001000000110010000000100100000010000011000000010001000001011000110000110000011100011100000011000000010010011000100000000000000100100000010110001100001000000111';
echo bin2base64($bin);
```

Result:

```
kDICQIMBEFjDBxwMBJiAASBYwgc=
```

---

Here's also function for decoding it back to string of binary digits:

```
function base64bin($str) {
    $result = '';
    $str = base64_decode($str);
    $len = strlen($str);
    for ( $n = 0; $n < $len; $n++ ) {
        $result .= str_pad(decbin(ord($str[$n])), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(base64bin(bin2base64($bin)) === $bin);
```

Result:

```
boolean true
```

Comment: I think that'll do. Thanks (:

Comment: @egasimus, I have added *decoder* as well, so you can convert them in both ways. Feel free to up-vote an answer, if you like it :) Ah, and I forgot to warn that string's length must be `n*8`, i.e., string with 12 binary numbers would give unexpected results.

Comment: Sorry for un-accepting your answer - I compared your function to base_convert in base36; for '100000011111110100000000', your function returns 'gf0AAA==', and base_convert(36) returns '52L8G' (or 'bets' without the last 4 zeros, which are just padding). So there obviously is a better solution, and I'm determined to find it. :)

Comment: @egasimus, I get "gf0A", not "GF0AA==". It would also be easier to help if you told what exactly you're trying to achieve, as "a better solution" is very generic term. E.g., 100% consistent and trusty results seems good enough solution to me.

Comment: This works well.  If you want to avoid = signs, just make sure that the number of 0's and 1's are a multiple of 24  (8 bits per ASCII char and 6 bits per base 64 character)  the equals come up when you are creating the final character in base64, but you don't have the right number of bits.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a built in base 64 encoding function, see documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php). If you want the decimal value of the binary string first use [bin2dec](https://www.php.net/bindec), there are similar functions for hexadecimals by the way. The documentation is your friend here.

[EDIT]

I might have misunderstood your question, if you want to convert between actual bases (base 2 and 64) use [base_convert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)

Comment: `base_convert()` is not precise with large numbers, it can't even handle 32bit numbers on 32bit system. `bin2dec()` also should not be used for large numbers.

Comment: @binaryLV: Indeed, per the warning on the function's page on PHP.net

Answer (score 0):

<strike>To convert a binary number (2 base) to a 64 base use the [`base_convert` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php).</strike>

```
$number = 1001000000110010000000100100000010000011000000010001000001011000110000110000011100011100000011000000010010011000100000000000000100100000010110001100001000000111;
base_convert ($number , 2, 64);
```

Comment: base_convert only accepts arguments between 2 and 36 inclusive.

Comment: @Meglio So it does. I probably should have noticed that when I answered this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = 1001000000110010000000100100000010000011000000010001000001011000110000110000011100011100000011000000010010011000100000000000000100100000010110001100001000000111;
echo base64_encode ($number);
```

This is if you want the exact string be converted into Base 64.

Comment: Here, $number is interpreted as a decimal number, not a binary one.